# How to use Django queries on a different machine

Tags: python, django

I have two servers. One is for database/Django (Machine A) the other one is for calculating stuff (Machine B). How could I enter data from Machine B to the database on Machine A while using django models.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to do some calculations on `Machine B` and update values in database on `Machine A`.

If you need to use django models on `Machine B` then I'd set up same application that is on `Machine A`. It won't serve requests, you don't need http server in front of it.

It's required to set correct values for `DATABASE_SETTINGS` pointing to `Machine A`. In this case you can move you calculations stuff to some [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and use plain `from app.models import MyModel`. Any changes like `MyModel.save()`, `MyModel.update()`, etc - will affect your single database.